# How do you progress from Insane levels to the Nightmare difficulty level?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

My friends and I have been playing Dungeon Defenders on PC for a few weeks now.  We have a variety of characters of at least level 70, usually focused on either towers or DPS (few hybrid builds in our group).  We've cleared the campaign on Insane difficulty (with a fair bit of trial and error, but we did it), but we can't even beat the first wave of the first map on Nightmare.

Any tips?  Are there stats we should be focusing on, such as resistances?  Items we should look out for?

Answer (score 3):

Nightmare is hard to do without 70+ upgrade armor/weapons.

I would also suggest making sure your characters run with guardian pets instead of any other types as they will buff towers significantly (unless you're a DPS character, then a different one can work), use a mix to do what is best, but an Apprentice guardian is key (it increases damage done by towers/traps).

I would suggest trying to do Uber Monster Fest. That or trying to run a few Mixed Mode Survival maps on insane (Alchemy lab is the easiest to do this on). Both these will start dropping 50+ upgrade items that you can use.

I would strong suggest Uber monster fest though, even if you fail the map as a whole, as long as you can make it past the first wave you will get upgrades, you don't even have to make it past the first wave, just the drops that the monsters give you will probably be upgrades at this point.

Comment: Should points in those 50+ level armour pieces go into the resistances, or focus on relevant stats for towers or the hero?  How valuable are resistance points?

Comment: Later on maxing out on resistances is important, it helps survivability A LOT. That said, if you have a monk with strength draining and healing aura you can skimp out a little bit and put more into things like damage/health. A monk aura buffed with the apprentice guardian can heal almost 1000/tick.

Comment: The guardians only buff one tower at a time, I think you are overestimating their worth

Comment: All guardians buff up to 5 towers/traps at a time. It's their "Defenses to boost" stat.

Answer (score 2):

Easy answer: Towers. DPS will not do, unless you are all in level 74 with high DPS and there are only 4 entrances. One that you don't cover, and you're toast.

So, towers towers towers...

Only way to do this, get to level 74. there is no other way.
Play on insane in Glitterhelm Caverns (the bonus map). It will give you more xp. 
Or better in Mystifire.

Once you're at 74 you can start using mythical armors and pets.

There you look for items with 150+ points for towers.

Easiest way: Buy them. There are guys that sells a set of armor, a weapon and a pet at high levels for $10.

Hard (and a little more satisfying) use the help of a 74 high character to build your defenses in Mystimire forest in Nightmare Hardcore. At wave 20-25 the monsters start dropping such items.

That's all the mystery

;)

Comment: I would say that buying items with real money is a Very Bad Idea because Trendy bans people for selling/buying with real money.

Comment: I never heard of anyone banned, but your warning is fair. One should know that it can happen. A risk that one may take or not.
Thanks for pointing that up.

Comment: also spoils the fun. Wave 1 Endless Spires is very manageable with tower stats ~250, ideally +genie, and 100k+ dps. Then pop the chests in the build time and gather any loot. You can get a set of mythical gear in a few (~5) rinses and repeats.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle. I found that Foundries and Forges is the best way to transition. Its an easy way to get myths to start you out. When I tried to make the transition to Nightmare I would keep trying to play the first level and found that to be much harder.  Get a few pure Tower characters and take on Foundries, even if you can only survive one or two levels, you will get some myths. After that, the easiest level is Endless Spires. Don't waste your money and take on the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Try leveling up some more. When you get a good DPS build with a high health, go for the endless spires on nightmare. Build a harpoon and a spike blockade at each choke, either kill the ogre, or just stall him till he despawns (I had to do this once, I was stuck as my hybrid squire). Grab all the chests and BAM you've got mythical gear!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the first wave of endless spires nightmare hardcore. You dont need very high stats, I did it with 100-200s. Harpoons can take care of normal enemies and if you go near your defenses (apprentice/huntress guardian) when sharkens attack you can take care of them. When the ogre attacks you just need to kite him with a dps ranged character. it might take a couple of minutes but he doesn't regen and so he will eventually die. You will probably get a myth within 3 runs.

A great dps weapon for noobs is the spider crossbow from the mystimire assault challenge (don't know which number assault) just do the assault at any difficulty and the weapon is great for this